# Only allow a subset of users to access a a managed package

Tags: managed-package

Is there a way to allow only a certain set of users?  The only way that I can think of this is installing the managed package for admins, and then turning on several components for the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the ISV Guide for the LMA (License Management App):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/lma_overview.htm

Using the LMA, you can issue a certain number of seats to the subscribing org and the admin of the org can choose which users to assign those licenses to:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=distribution_managing_licenses.htm&language=en_US

> When you install a licensed managed package in your organization from AppExchange, you purchase a certain number of licenses from the package developer or publisher. You can assign each license to a user within your organization. If you assign all available licenses, but would like to grant licenses to additional users, you can reassign a license or purchase more. To get more licenses, contact the publisher of the managed package.

If your question is asking about whether the admin of a subscribing org can control licensing if the publisher hasn't issued seat licenses (i.e. it's an unlimited/free app), then the answer is No. The only way to control access in that case is to use Permission Sets (preferred) or Profiles to grant access to the package components.